# which approach lets me solve this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$y^2u_x+xyu_y=xu(u+1)$$

I have tried using the method of characteristics but it led me to some complicated equations that I couldn't integrate.
so I suspect there must be another way of solving this.

if anybody can help me it would be great. thanks.

EDIT : by using the following change of variables

- $ξ = y^2-x^2$
- $\eta = x $
  and letting $\overline{u}(ξ,\eta) = u(x,y)$
  after rearranging I ended up getting this equation :

$$y^2\overline{u}_{\eta} = xu(u+1)$$

which after integrating I got this implicit formula of $u$ :

$$\ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right) = \frac{x^2}{2y^2} + \phi (y^2-x^2)$$

I hope I didn't make any mistake in the process of computation

but I still haven't figured out a way to determine an explicit formula of $u$

EDIT2 : 
\begin{align}
y^2\overline{u}_{\eta} = \eta u(u+1) \\
\frac{\overline{u}_{\eta}}{u(u+1)} = \frac{\eta}{y^2} \\
\end{align}

after integrating with respect to $\eta$

\begin{align}
\ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right) =  \frac{\eta^2}{2y^2} + \phi(ξ)\\
\end{align}

since 
  $ξ = y^2-x^2$, $\eta = x $

then

$$\ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right) = \frac{x^2}{2y^2} + \phi (y^2-x^2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree with your result : $\quad\ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right) = \frac{x^2}{2y^2} + \phi (y^2-x^2)$

Without all steps of your calculus one cannot say exactly where is the mistake.

You should get to:
$$\ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right) = \ln|y| + \phi (y^2-x^2)$$

Then, in order to express the result on explicit form :
$$\frac{u}{u+1} = y \:\exp\left(\phi (y^2-x^2)\right)$$
Solving for $u$ leads to :
$$u=\frac{y}{\exp\left(\phi (y^2-x^2)\right) -y}$$
Equivalently, with the change of function $F(y^2-x^2)=\exp\left(\phi (y^2-x^2)\right)$ :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{y}{F(y^2-x^2) -y}$$
Putting this result back into the PDE shows that it agrees. This confirms  that it is the correct result.
$$ $$
IN ADDITION :
$$y^2u_x+xyu_y=xu(u+1)$$
System of ODEs for characteristics : $\quad\frac{dx}{y^2}=\frac{dy}{xy}=\frac{du}{xu(u+1)}$

First family of characteristic curves , from $\quad \frac{dx}{y^2}=\frac{dy}{xy} \quad\to\quad y^2-x^2=c_1$

Second family of characteristic curves , from $\quad \frac{dy}{xy}=\frac{du}{xu(u+1)}\quad\to\quad \ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1} \right)-\ln(y)=c_2$

General solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation :
$$\Phi\left(\ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1} \right)-\ln(y) \:,\: y^2-x^2 \right)=0$$
$\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

Or equivalently, on the form:
$$\ln\left(\frac{u}{u+1} \right)-\ln(y)=\phi(y^2-x^2)$$
$\phi$ is any differentiable function.

Finally, solve it for $u$ as shown above.

Comment: thanks for the answer 

check my edit and see if you can spot the mistake also if you can tell me which approach you used it would be great.

but I suspect I know my mistake the $y$ should depend on $\eta$ since $ξ = y^2-x^2$ and $\eta = x$

Comment: Yes, that is why the integration with regard to $\eta$ cannot be done with $y$ in the function to be integrated. I will edit my calculus. The method is different from the method you used, but related.